# Can I sell maps to third parties if I have Google Earth Pro License?

Tags: google-maps, cartography, license, google-earth-enterprise, google-earth-pro

Not sure if this question is suitable for SE but I can't find answers anywhere else.

I work as a GIS Analyst for a mining company that has its own GEPro license.  As part of my job, I make PDF maps, which are then used externally on the company's website for promotional purposes.  The maps display geological information, with GE satellite imagery as a base layer.

Per my understanding of GEPro's TOS, this is acceptable.  I am an employee of a company which has a valid license, and I am making maps on their behalf.

Now for the tricky part.  I am starting to do freelance/contract map work for other companies.  I have my own GEPro license, and would be delivering to my clients PDF maps of geological data with satellite imagery as the base layer.  The clients would then use the PDF maps externally, for promotional purposes. I think that this would classify my clients as "Third Parties".

As far as I see it there are three options:

1) Making maps for third parties for a fee is acceptable with a GEPro license

2) Making maps for third parties for a fee is acceptable with a GE Enterprise license

3) I can make as many maps as I want, so long as the company I'm making them for has a valid GEPro license

...

I've read over most everything Google has put out as far as TOS goes, but clarity is hard to come by.  The GE Enterprise TOS talks about not selling "Intermediate Data Products" or "Fused Databases", but I dont think those are applicable to what I would be providing (though admittedly, I am not crystal clear on what those two terms mean).

Anyone have any insight/experience with this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: When it comes to questions of legality, *"what am I allowed to do with..."*, we can't help you. Or rather the community can and will provide answers, but it would be foolish to base business decisions (solely) on them. You need to contact the company licensing department directly for a definitive answer. That said I'm leaving the question open because it is exceptionally well written, and there are many who will be in a similar position and find the discussion helpful (witness the [tag:license] tag).

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have found that, but it seems to be what is the most precise answer for your question:
[Permissions - Google](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html)

Answer (score -1):

I was just looking at this.
[get in touch](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/earthpro.html?utm_source=gdn&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=earthpro-icm-scm-main&gclid=CJeVnYKJ-rcCFQ3l7AodVWMAdA#display=cs-dialog-form)
[On the google enterprise software comparison page](http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/earthpro.html?utm_source=gdn&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=earthpro-icm-scm-main&gclid=CJeVnYKJ-rcCFQ3l7AodVWMAdA#)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I've read about 300 web pages discussing this, but still haven't found any definitive answers.  After reading all the legal docs for both Pro and Enterprise, I feel good that what I'm doing is legal with a Pro license.  Still waiting for official word back from Google (about 10 emails over 12 days), but when I get the answer I'll post it here.

It is incredibly frustrating, though, that Google's terms are so vague on this (likely, a deliberate move by them).

Comment: Well, it's been over a month.. still no reply from anyone at Google.  I've since decided to just go ahead and use it the way I need to, as I think it's in the spirit of the terms.  Though I have put the license in the name of a corporation I set up, and will be charging everything out through that corporation..  Hopefully that will mitigate the risk somewhat..